# Compiler error with gmock and boost::signals2

Tags: c++, boost, googlemock

I have extracted the code with does not compile anymore. With boost 1.70 and gmock 1.7.2 the code compiles without any error but with newer libraries boost 1.72 and gmock 1.10 it does not compile anymore. The error below is quite cryptic.

Every help is very much appreciated.

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

using ::testing::Return;
using ::testing::_; // Matcher for parameters

class M{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(connect, boost::signals2::connection(boost::signals2::signal<void(int)>::slot_type slot));
};

TEST(A,B){
    M m;

    ON_CALL(m, connect(_)).WillByDefault(Return(boost::signals2::connection{}));
}

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the compiler output:

```
In file included from /home/xxx/mycode2/google-googletest/examples/test/main.cpp:1:
In file included from /home/xxx/my/boost_1_72_0/include/boost/signals2.hpp:19:
In file included from /home/xxx/my/boost_1_72_0/include/boost/signals2/signal.hpp:22:
In file included from /home/xxx/my/boost_1_72_0/include/boost/signals2/connection.hpp:24:
In file included from /home/xxx/my/boost_1_72_0/include/boost/signals2/slot.hpp:30:
In file included from /home/xxx/my/boost_1_72_0/include/boost/signals2/variadic_slot.hpp:24:
/home/xxx/my/boost_1_72_0/include/boost/signals2/detail/slot_template.hpp:160:26: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::tuple<boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> > &&>'
        _slot_function = detail::get_invocable_slot(f, detail::tag_type(f));
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/xxx/my/boost_1_72_0/include/boost/signals2/detail/slot_template.hpp:85:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> >::init_slot_function<std::tuple<boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> > &&> >' requested here
        init_slot_function(f);
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/tuple:133:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> >::slot<std::tuple<boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> > &&> >' requested here
        : _M_head_impl(std::forward<_UHead>(__h)) { }
          ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:285:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'testing::Action<boost::signals2::connection (boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> >)>::ActionAdapter::operator()<boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> > >' requested here
        return (*_Base::_M_get_pointer(__functor))(
               ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:676:33: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::_Function_handler<boost::signals2::connection (boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> >), testing::Action<boost::signals2::connection (boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> >)>::ActionAdapter>::_M_invoke' requested here
            _M_invoker = &_My_handler::_M_invoke;
                                       ^
/home/xxx/my/googletest/install-release-1.10.0-508-g5a509dbd/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h:477:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::function<boost::signals2::connection (boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> >)>::function<testing::Action<boost::signals2::connection (boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> >)>::ActionAdapter, void, void>' requested here
      : fun_(ActionAdapter{::std::shared_ptr<ActionInterface<F>>(impl)}) {}
        ^
/home/xxx/my/googletest/install-release-1.10.0-508-g5a509dbd/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h:662:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'testing::Action<boost::signals2::connection (boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> >)>::Action' requested here
    return Action<F>(new Impl<R, F>(value_));
           ^
/home/xxx/mycode2/google-googletest/examples/test/main.cpp:16:42: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'testing::internal::ReturnAction<boost::signals2::connection>::operator Action<boost::signals2::connection (boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> >)>' requested here
    ON_CALL(m, connect(_)).WillByDefault(Return(boost::signals2::connection{}));
                                         ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/tuple:640:17: note: explicitly defaulted function was implicitly deleted here
      constexpr tuple(const tuple&) = default;
                ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/tuple:523:19: note: copy constructor of 'tuple<boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> > &&>' is implicitly deleted because base class '_Tuple_impl<0, boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> > &&>' has a deleted copy constructor
    class tuple : public _Tuple_impl<0, _Elements...>
                  ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/tuple:351:17: note: explicitly defaulted function was implicitly deleted here
      constexpr _Tuple_impl(const _Tuple_impl&) = default;
                ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/tuple:327:7: note: copy constructor of '_Tuple_impl<0, boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> > &&>' is implicitly deleted because base class '_Head_base<0UL, boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> > &&>' has a deleted copy constructor
    : private _Head_base<_Idx, _Head>
      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/tuple:128:17: note: explicitly defaulted function was implicitly deleted here
      constexpr _Head_base(const _Head_base&) = default;
                ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/tuple:165:13: note: copy constructor of '_Head_base<0, boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> > &&, false>' is implicitly deleted because field '_M_head_impl' is of rvalue reference type 'boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> > &&'
      _Head _M_head_impl;
            ^
/home/xxx/my/boost_1_72_0/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1119:21: note: passing argument to parameter 'f' here
  operator=(Functor f)
                    ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I can make this work

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

using ::testing::_; // Matcher for parameters
using ::testing::Return;

struct M {
    MOCK_METHOD1(connect, boost::signals2::connection(boost::signals2::signal<void(int)>::slot_type slot));
};

TEST(A, B) {
    M m;
    ON_CALL(m, connect(_)).WillByDefault(Return(boost::signals2::connection{}));
}
```

by using this CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(stackoverflow)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS TRUE)

set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS On)
set(BOOST_ROOT "/home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0")
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system REQUIRED)

#include(GoogleTest)
enable_testing()
find_package(GMock REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
ADD_EXECUTABLE(sotest test.cpp)

target_link_libraries(sotest ${BOOST_system_LIBRARY_RELEASE})
target_link_libraries(sotest gmock_main)
#gtest_add_tests(sotest "" AUTO)
```

Which then runs with

```
cmake .
cmake --build .
./sotest
```

Printing

[image]

> **PS:** I removed `int amin(){}` from your source program to get the mock main

> Also, I verified that the include path is for Boost 1.74.0 by inspecting `compile_command.json`:

```
  "command": "/usr/bin/c++   -I/home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0 -I/usr/src/googletest/googlemock/include -I/usr/src/googletest/googletest/include    -o CMakeFiles/sotest.dir/test.cpp.o -c /home/sehe/Projects/mockingbird/test.cpp",
```

Comment: Mmm. It appears I have gmock 1.8.0. That might be a factor

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I think it's a google test thing. I bisect and the bad commit is `9494c45e75a55547f3f183a1161fbd39d29b994e`. So I changed the function's argument to `std::function<void(int)>` then it's working even with gmock 1.10.

Comment: In case it helps you compare, I preprocessed the `M` declaration and manually simplified the resulting gibberish using typedefs. If you do the same with your version of the code you might spot what no longer works: https://gist.github.com/sehe/925b9f1b04df20efeef94072e52b5e21 (confirmed to still work after expanding)

Comment: Reading the original error message it looks like the complaint is that `std::tuple<F::ArgumentTuple>` has a deleted copy constructor (which isn't the case for me). However, that's NOT a gmock problem at all, because only Boost and std types are involved.

Comment: You can check whether [`static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<std::tuple<boost::signals2::slot<void (int), boost::function<void (int)> > > >::value)`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AatdagKEqeNbCR5m) passes on your platform.

Comment: Better spelling of the slot type to allow for potential boost version changes https://wandbox.org/permlink/jniKjIUKHe2vbKNk

Comment: I can't find a config that fails the assert. Would be very interesting to see whether it passes for you [link table](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zbYK96XZGV/). I even thought to test Clang with libc++ instead of libstdc++ in a few

Comment: The assert passes on my machine too. If I checkout one gmock commit before the above commit it works, therefore I think the *Use std::function to implement type erasure in Action, wrapping the legacy ActionInterface if necessary* commit messes all up. Thank you for your help anyway.